# Fix missing permissions with "role delete" when i trigger guildDelete event

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Bot Permissions: **Admin** (all permissions)
Bot Role at the top of the list

I've tried this code:

```js
client.on("guildDelete", async guild => {
    try {
        await guild.roles.find(r => r.id == "123456789").delete()
    }
    catch(err){
    // Missing Permissions
    }
})
```

But, i tried this too (simulate the guildDelete event)

> argument "guild" is a real guild

```js
client.emit("guildDelete", guild)
// This time, the role is deleted...
```

Why this time it works but not on the real event?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to remove a role when the client deletes the guild/server? If so, then won't guild no longer be found if it is deleted? Also, Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: When i invite the bot in the guild, it create 3 roles, i want when the bot leave the guild, he delete these 3 roles. There is no error except the "missing permissions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guildDelete` event being triggered means that the account of your bot was removed from that Guild, either through it leaving itself, being kicked, being banned, or the Guild being deleted.

Not being in the Guild anymore will make your Bot unable to interact with anything from that Guild, thus throwing an invalid permission error.

When you are using `client.emit` you are simulating the Event being triggered, meaning that your Bot is still in the Guild and still has access.

Comment: Okay, i didn't see this like this. I was thinking i can to do something before the bot leave the guild... I want, when the bot leave, it delete these roles it create when it enters the guild